# SQL in Pairing Corresponding Duplicated Rows and Calculate Days Between (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table contain different types of transactions processed for a mortgage collateral. I am providing a reporting solution to help user determine the number of days between two separate transactions. The challenge that I am facing is that a set of transaction can occur multiple times and I don't know how to pair one transaction to another corresponding transaction and calculate the number of days between those two transactions. For example, I have a table containing transaction for 1 collateral that were returned and reinstated multiple times. Each time a return occurs, a transaction is posted in this table and same for the reinstatement:

```
transaction type    collateral  transaction date
reinstatement       123         11/24/2013
returned            123         11/21/2013
reinstatement       123         1/2/2013
returned            123         1/1/2013
```

Rule 1: a returned transaction must be followed by a reinstatement

Rule 2: There is no relationship that links between the two corresponding transactions

Results:

```
collateral  days between transactions
123         1
123         3
```

Currently, I have to run an extract of all returned and reinstatement transactions then have to manually pair up each transaction then calculate days in between. Could anyone have a possible solution include this logic in SQL? I am currently using SQL Server 2008. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to let us know if an answer has resolved your issue.

Comment: @Mack. Thank you for this solution. Although, I will have to add in additional logics to the query. Utilizing row_number seems to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT's not the prettiest of queries and I don't have a vast expanse of test data but this will accomplish your needs with the data you have given:

```
--Test Data
CREATE TABLE MORTGAGE (transactionType VARCHAR(20),collateral INT, transactionDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO MORTGAGE VALUES('reinstatement',123,'Nov 24 2013')
INSERT INTO mortgage VALUES('returned',123,'Nov 21 2013')
INSERT INTO mortgage VALUES('reinstatement',123,'Jan 2 2013')
INSERT INTO mortgage VALUES('returned',123,'Jan 1 2013')

--Query
SELECT res1.collateral
     , DATEDIFF(DAY,res1.transactiondate,res2.transactiondate) AS [days between transactions]
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
        TRANSACTIONTYPE, 
        COLLATERAL, 
        TRANSACTIONDATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by transactiontype order by transactiondate) artificialid
     FROM MORTGAGE 
     WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPE='returned'
     ORDER BY transactionDate) res1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        TRANSACTIONTYPE, 
        COLLATERAL, 
        TRANSACTIONDATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by transactiontype order by transactiondate) artificialid
     FROM MORTGAGE mret
     WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPE='reinstatement'
     ORDER BY transactionDate) res2
ON res1.artificialid = res2.artificialid
AND res1.TRANSACTIONDATE <> res2.TRANSACTIONDATE 
AND res1.TRANSACTIONDATE <> res2.TRANSACTIONDATE 

--Results
collateral  days between transactions
123         1
123         3
```

Comment: @Mack...Thank you so much for this solution. I will definitely try this out.

Comment: @Mack...Thank you so much for this solution. I will try this and provide comment. Thank you again!